# Is removing the paper tag off the papercutting questions really necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, specific-question

So there were pending edits, which I rejected, to remove [paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) from the following questions:

[What medium should be kept beneath the paper for papercutting?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/218/what-medium-should-be-kept-beneath-the-paper-for-papercutting)

and

[What is a proper tool for papercutting?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/217/what-is-a-proper-tool-for-papercutting)

Under the tags page the second sentence reads:

> Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

The first is asking what they should be cutting *paper* on where the second is asking about what tool to use to cut *paper*.

[paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) seems very appropriate in both cases. OK so perhaps the argument is that [papercutting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papercutting) renders [paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) redundant. The community might see otherwise and remove them.

What *actual harm* is caused by that tag being there? I would argue, at a minimum, that [paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) gives those questions more visibility. I don't think it makes the question worse.

Answer (score 2):

Paper tags should be for questions **about** paper... not questions that just happen to involve paper.

The questions are not asking for help selecting paper, they're asking for help picking out a knife/blade and a mat...

Papercutting in itself **implies** paper. Why do we need **both** [paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) **and** [paper-cutting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-cutting) on all questions about paper cutting? The tags are redundant.

Comment: It is a valid argument I just don't know what bad could come of them being there. Do we even really need paper then? Something else like origami also implies paper. Would there be questions about paper that don't involve a craft-like tag? I'm just curious is all.

Comment: Questions about drawing or watercolors could easily need a paper tag if someone is attempting to pick the correct type of paper to use.

Comment: Ah yes that would be true since you don't exclusively draw on paper. Good point.